# How to remove multiple redirection of homepage?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

my website homepage redirects multiple times. I want to remove these multiple redirections.

I hit the URL in browser http://example.com

First, It redirects to http://www.example.com

Finally, Redirected to https://www.example.com

But I want to redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

or without domain name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: @Vinodkumar those rules will work. Make sure you clear your browser cache that you might have from the old rules.

Comment: I have cleared cache. but still multiple redirection showing.

Comment: No other rule before in your .htaccess ?